# Terraform refer to locals in another directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I have a directory name "3-tier" In which there are two more directories namely ec2 and vpc. The exact directory structure is as attached below

[image]

The main.tf in vpc directory has a locals block defined:

```
locals {
    owner = var.owner
    environment = var.environment
    Name = "${local.owner}-${local.environment}-${var.vpc_name}"
    common_tags = {
        Owner = local.owner
        Environment = local.environment
        Name = local.Name
    }
}
```

In the ec2 directory main.tf file I have loaded the module as below

```
module "vpc_module" {
    source = "../vpc/"
}
```

How can I refer to the locals present in vpc directory main.tf file from ec2 directory main.tf file?

Comment: I have defined the outputs in vpc and used them in ec2. However, i am not satisfied with this approach.  Sadly looks like there is no other way.

Comment: That's how tf works. You have to accept it or simply not use tf. Nevertheless my answer is correct and it's acceptance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I refer to the locals present in vpc directory main.tf file from ec2 directory main.tf file?

You can't do this directly. You have to add them as `output` values to your `vpc` module. Then you will be able to access them through outputs of your vpc module.

Comment: Is there any way other than defining the output? Any global definition that we can define?

Comment: @vidyadharreddy No, there is no such way.